# Access to Metallb IPs is not possible

Tags: networking, kubernetes, ingress

I have a k8s cluster with 3 masters and 7 workers. I have many services on it and I want to expose some of them. I used Metallb for this task and with layer 2 configuration I can get IPs from IP pool and assign to services. But I cannot reach these IPs outside of the cluster. Here's my configuration:

```
apiVersion: metallb.io/v1beta1
kind: IPAddressPool
metadata:
  name: first-pool
  namespace: metallb-system
spec:
  addresses:
  - 192.168.36.0/24
  - 192.168.9.1-192.168.9.5
  - fc00:f853:0ccd:e799::/124
```

and this is the advertisement:

```
apiVersion: metallb.io/v1beta1
kind: L2Advertisement
metadata:
  name: example
  namespace: metallb-system
spec:
  ipAddressPools:
  - first-pool
```

For example I want to reach 192.168.36.5 that is for the nginx service from a machine in local network (but outside of the clusetr).
Note that the service with assigned IP address by Metallb can be reached from the cluster.